# How to dynamically import images in astro.js framework components(react specifically)?

Tags: vite, astrojs, dynamic-import

I have a json file containing an array of object's in following format

```
[

{

name : "foo",

image : "/src/assets/default.webp"

},

{

name : "Jonas",

image : "https://..."

]
```

Then in my astro file , I am simply importing the json , iterating over it and passing the data to my react components

i.e

```
---

import data from "../data.json"

---



data.map((e) => {

<Reactcomponent data={data} client:load/>

})
```

Reactcomponent.jsx

```
export default function React component({data}) {



return (

<>

<p>{data.name}</p>

<img src={data.image} alt="..." />

</>

)



}
```

It works just fine in dev mode but in production I have had no luck so far

I can see the images in my dist/_astro folder but they've been renamed and when I inspect the image's in build mode their path remains the same /src/assets/imgname

But in the build there is no src or assets folder and the images also have been renamed

Tbh I am not even sure that the images i am seeing in the dist/_astro folder have something to do with them being used in json

I have read the documentation and it only shows examples of static imports , i have heard about a vite plugin that uses the import() function but it has its own issues , is there any "natural" way to do it  or available API for it

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this recipe in the docs for a guide on [how to Dynamically Import Images](https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/dynamically-importing-images/)